# RecyclerView adapter slow when notifyItemInserted in scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, chat

I am using a `RecyclerView` to view the messages in chat application 
when I recieve a new message and i use `notifyItemInserted` the scrolling is slowing down why its happining and how to solve it ?

Comment: Can you show your relevant code ?

Comment: ConversationFragment.messagesRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(ConversationFragment.messagesRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount());

the problem just happened when i use this code

Comment: so how can we imagine what you are using, you must share more code ! Please edit your question

Comment: i use an asynctask to listen incoming messages from irc server 
so when i recieve a message i update the adapter like this way its long code i cant paste all the code to here

Comment: Dear friend, we need to see your `RecyclerView` row layout maybe the issue here, or maybe your method cause the problem. Right now noone knows what you have already. Make sure you read this page : [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.